How do I install curl?
I installed curl with install.packages("curl", type = "source"). When I try to do iDigBio_SA <- idig_search_records(rq=list(scientificname="Spartina alterniflora")) the following error pops up: Error in loadNamespace(x) : there is no package called ‘curl’
I have restarted and uninstalled curl but it is still occurring. Not sure how to resolve.

If there is no package, there was an issue in the installation. Did any error get returned with install.packages()?

I currently am getting "Error in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...) :
unable to load shared object '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.4-arm64/Resources/library/curl/libs/curl.so':
dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.4-arm64/Resources/library/curl/libs/curl.so, 0x0006): symbol not found in flat namespace (_curl_url_strerror)" after "iDigBio_SA <- idig_search_records(rq=list(scientificname="Spartina alterniflora"))"

You probably need to install curl brew install curl.

Check if curl is installed properly in your device by typing curl --version in the cmd in windows or else if you are using a mac type curl --version in the terminal.
